# didUpdateToLocation not called second time

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

In our app, I'm using CoreLocation to get user's location. I thought the call to startUpdatingLocation would invoke locationManager:didUpdateLocations every time. But once it's getting called for first time, they never get called anymore.

In my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void) startStandardUpdates {
 if (_locationManager == nil) {
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [_locationManager setDelegate:self];
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    _locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

 } else {
    NSLog(@"[LOCATION]: Location Manager already exists.");
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
 }
}
```

Then call it by NSTimer:

```
- (void) startTask {
  NSLog(@"Start task called.");
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15
                                   target:self
                                 selector:@selector(actualTask)
                                 userInfo:nil
                                  repeats:YES];
}

- (void) actualTask {
  NSLog(@"[TASK]: Starting location service...");
  [self startStandardUpdates];
}
```

The above code should call startUpdatingLocation every 15 seconds but the didUpdateToLocation method not getting called for the second time (the first one successfully called...).

Is there a way to call (or force) didUpdateToLocation 'programmatically'? Or we have to wait until didUpdateToLocation gets the location? I have searched around the way to get user's location every x minutes/seconds but no one seems to successfully achieved that. What I would like to do is just the equivalent of how Android do it with Service class (iOS doesn't have this).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?. I have the same problem now. But its updating only five times. After that its getting stop itself. In the simulator, its working fine. Please help me in this.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, still no "solid" solution for my problem. I don't know if it could help, but in your case, perhaps the OS killing your logic for background task timeout? I once had the case when I forgot to check "Required background modes" in Info Settings...

Comment: I got the solution for my problem. In iOS6 we should use "didUpdateLocations" instead of "didUpdateToLocation". That was what problem. Now working fine.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem :) I was also had that probolem and asked a question about it... Anyway, keep up the good work and have a nice coding!

Answer (score 5):

_locationManager.distanceFilter=10;
your distance filter is set to 10m you will not be notified. Once the position has moved enough to exceed your distance filter setting then you will get a didUpdateToLocation callback...

Comment: Thank you for reply! So it's relevant to the current position? If so, the freeway driving mode in simulator should work and call didUpdateToLocation perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Once you startUpdatingLocation it's going. Pretty much non-stop, based on the accuracy you selected, so there isn't a need to keep starting it. It will wait for significant location changes that match your accuracy... it handles all this efficiency and power tradeoff stuff for you. Did you try using the simulator and selecting the driving route option? It might help you get more of a sense of it in motion (only start it once).

If you simply need it to give you that ping every 15 seconds then maybe start updating... and then simply read the current location/heading every 15 seconds in your timer?

```
- (void) actualTask {
    NSLog("Currently at: %@", MyLocationManager.location.coordinate);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! Actually, I'm calling stopStandardUpdates inside didUpdateToLocation once the location is determined. Hence I had to keep starting startStandardUpdates. This is also to have extra background remaining time. I have also tried Freeway driving mode in simulator, but still I couldn't receive didUpdateToLocation after the first time update...

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are in building or complex then `didUpdateLocations` will not called. if you can real time test like take build on device on just move on to open space so GPS can get the data and you will receive the data. if you walk then it also not get frequently `didUpdateLocations`. you have to test on car/bus or in bike.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, change `distancefilter=10` to `kCLDistanceFilterNone`